# Who use javaFX for commercial quality games?

Tags: java

Are there any companies work with javaFX for building videos games ?

Comment: This isn't really appropriate for this site. It's asking for a list, and it's asking about industry trivia and not about a practical problem you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

I have to say that the current build JavaFX 8 is very well suitable for professional games at least for 2D.
The big advantage is that JavaFX has a very professional GUI library which makes it very suitable for UI heavy games.

Answer (score 1):

JavaFX was not built with speed in mind, therefore the JavaFX 2D and 3D libraries are too slow.

I suggest you use JOGL from www.jogamp.org. This library is more than commercially viable.